# WSO2 api manager is not sending data to WSO2 DAS (Data analytics server)

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I configured API manager to send data to WSO2 data analytics server.

My configuration on API server is:

Event Receiver Configurations: {tcp://wso2-dac-svc.libre-dev.com:7611}
Data Analyzer Configurations: https://wso2-dac-svc.libre-dev.com:8443

On DAC server I installed API_Manager_Analytics.car which has event receiver definitions.

On API server I have imported certificate from DAC server using keytool. I restarted both servers.

I am seeing following error in the log:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2016-05-16 16:06:11,417] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher} -  Error while connection to event receiver {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: Access denied for user admin to login TCP,wso2-dac-svc.libre-dev.com:7611,TCP,wso2-dac-svc.libre-dev.com:7711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.start(DataPublisher.java:273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:161)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher$ReceiverConnectionWorker.run(AsyncDataPublisher.java:843)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentAuthenticatorException: Thrift exception
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.ThriftAgentAuthenticator.connect(ThriftAgentAuthenticator.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:51)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:147)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:163)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:91)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.send_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.ThriftAgentAuthenticator.connect(ThriftAgentAuthenticator.java:47)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:145)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
        at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValidator.java:394)
        at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:133)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        ... 23 more
TID: [-1] [] [2016-05-16 16:06:41,363] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher} -  Reconnection failed fortcp://wso2-dac-svc.libre-dev.com:7611 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-05-16 16:07:11,004]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:6ed9fae5-d1fb-4cdf-885b-e101e79faf40; dropping message after timeout of : 30 seconds {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-05-16 16:07:11,371] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher} -  Reconnection failed fortcp://wso2-dac-svc.libre-dev.com:7611 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-05-16 16:07:34,514]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  http-outgoing-9: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
```

Basically I cannot get API stats sent to DAS server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you changed keystore/truststore files either in APIM or DAS?

Comment: WSO2 DAS server was presenting itself as a localhost and therefore dashboard wasn't working, so I had to create a new certificate and replace it in wso2carbon.jks and client-truststore.jks.

Comment: So your problem was resolved?

Comment: No my problem is not resolved. I am still facing exactly same issue, I just answer the question.

Comment: Do you sign those certificates using a CA or are self signed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error log the issue seems to be wit

The Data Analytic Server Thrift runs on port 7711 uses the 'wso2carbon.jks' located in /repository/resources/security by deault. As a result when we need to configure this  on /repository/conf/carbon.xml as shown below

```
<Security> <br>
    <!--<br>
        KeyStore which will be used for encrypting/decrypting passwords<br>
        and other sensitive information.
    --><br>
    <KeyStore><br>
        <!-- Keystore file location--><br>
        <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location><br>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)--><br>
        <Type>JKS</Type><br>
        <!-- Keystore password--><br>
        <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
        <!-- Private Key alias--><br>
        <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
        <!-- Private Key password-->
        <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword><br>
    </KeyStore><br>
```

For adding a new key store please use the below steps 
1. Place the key store in '/repository/resources/security/' folder 
2. Update the section 'Security/KeyStore/' of /repository/conf/carbon.xml accordingly
3. Update the keystore references of the data-agent-config.xml accordingly
4. Import the certificate of the new keystore to ESB's trust store located at /repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks.

Finally, once the private key is changed, its relevent certificate should be imported to the API-Manager trust store located at /repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks.

Hope this steps will sort the issues on the given error log.